# `<PBX...`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter, macos-catalina

I have purchased a new Macbook Air 2020 and I wanted to test my flutter app using an iOS simulator.
However, an error is shown here every time I run my app. My Flutter app is working fine on the Android part but I want to see it on the iOS simulator as well.
I am using Android Studio (for Flutter Dev) and XCode 12 is installed on my Mac.
Here I have given the error :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_ml_vision` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_ml_vision/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.32.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.5/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.7/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.9/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.3/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.4/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.5/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.6/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.7/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.9/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.10/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.11/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.1.12/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.2.3/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.0.3/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.1.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.2.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.3.3/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.4.3/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/2.5.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.2.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.5.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.7.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.11.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/3.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.3/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.0.4/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.1.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.8.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.10.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/4.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.0.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.4.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.8.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.18.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.19.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.20.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.20.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.1.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.8.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.9.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.12.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.18.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.19.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.21.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.22.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.23.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.24.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.29.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.30.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.31.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.31.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.32.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.32.2/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_ml_vision":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_ml_vision (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_ml_vision/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `firebase_ml_vision (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_ml_vision/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:986:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:984:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:233:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

[!] `<PBXGroup UUID=`97C146E51CF9000F007C117D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `CF3B75C9A7D2FA2A4C99F110` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
```

Please help me, I am stuck here for almost 2 days.

Comment: @Kshitz have you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Hey there!
Remove the invalidated caches and try to clean your whole project. 
If this doesn't work,

Answer (score 0):

So after so much search, I didn't got any concrete solution to this problem.

Any of these methods can work for you as it also depends on the current flutter version you are using :

Remove the invalidated caches and try to clean your whole project.
If this doesn't work,
Then try to upgrade your Flutter version

Or

1. flutter clean
2. delete /ios/Pods
3. delete /ios/Podfile.lock
4. flutter pub get
5. from inside ios folder: pod install Run